# node: command not found when installing firebase-tools

Tags: node.js, npm, firebase-tools

I am trying to install firebase-tools, but it keeps failing. here's the log.

```
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.3: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\win\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\node_modules\\proto3-json-serializer\\node_modules\\protobufjs',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir 'C:\Users\win\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\proto3-json-serializer\node_modules\protobufjs'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4082,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EBUSY',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\win\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\node_modules\\proto3-json-serializer\\node_modules\\protobufjs'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ],
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\win\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\node_modules\\@grpc',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\win\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\src\generated'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\win\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\node_modules\\@grpc\\grpc-js\\src\\generated'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ],
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\win\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\node_modules',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\win\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\@grpc'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\win\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\node_modules\\@grpc'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ],
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\win\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\win\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\google-gax\build'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\win\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\node_modules\\google-gax\\build'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ]
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path C:\Users\win\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\node_modules\protobufjs
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command bash -c node scripts/postinstall
npm ERR! /bin/bash: node: command not found

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\win\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-22T00_59_48_176Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried:

1. Reinstalling node (even trying different versions from 12 to 18)
2. running as admin
3. setting the `--unsafe-perm` flag (which I think doesn't work anymore anyway)
4. checking the node path (node is working normally anyway)

I can install other packages just fine. It's only this package and firebase.

I was expecting for it to install normally. My other machine installs it with no problem and I have the same set up ish

Comment: Your log suggests you are _extremely_ behind in updating your dependencies, and you should probably take some time to first get those back up to date with the current LTS version of Node. har-validator was discontinued _three years_ ago, so any dependency that still needs it is also heavily out of date - uuid is on v9, request has been superceded by native fetch, etc. Now is the right time to do some proper maintenance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `npm config delete script-shell` did the trick. It was trying to run a .sh script on windows.